# Como enviar arquivo para upload com PHP?

Tags: php, json, imagem, upload

Tenho uma função para realizar upload de arquivos, onde eu dependo de um form

```
<form method='post' action='http://localhost/api/uploadAPI.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'><br>
<input type='file' name='foto' value='Cadastrar foto'>
<input type='submit' name='submit'>
</form>
```

Dessa forma, funciona normalmente... O problema é que dependo de um form.

A missão é implementar de forma que eu possa enviar o arquivo tudo apenas via url mais ou menos assim em send.php:

```
<?php
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'key: MEU_TOKEN'; 

$data = array(
    "foto"=> [ 
        "name"      => "nome_do_arquivo.jpeg",
        "type"      => "image/jpeg",
        "tmp_name"  => "CAMINHO_DO_ARQUIVO",
        "error"     => 0,
        "size"      => 82804,
    ]
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_URL            => 'http://localhost/api/api.php?operacao=upload_img', 
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => $headers,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => json_encode($data),
    CURLOPT_POST           => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
]);
$out = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r( $out ); // Result json
```

Usando o form, eu consigo recuperar os dados em `$_FILES['foto']`
Como posso fazer para enviar o arquivo através do send.php para recuperá-lo na api com $_FILES['foto']?

Answer (score -1):

Já tentou implementar o método $_GET para enviar as informações para um arquivo intermediário tratando os dados, e depois resgatá-la e dar o fim desejado aos dados? Talvez possa funcionar, já que você quer passar os dados pela URL.

Comment: Desculpe, mas acho que não entendi o que disse... Você fala de criar uma página para carregar com as informações que eu quero e enviar o formulário? Se for isso, ainda assim, não sei como posso anexar o arquivo... Quando eu recupero o valor do campo via jquery $('input['type=foto]').val() eu tenho nomeDoArquivo.png, sendo que o arquivo encontra-se em C:\Users\Fotos\nomeDoArquivo.png